# How to put the machine IP address into the HAProxy config file with the help of Jinja2 template and Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory

I have some misunderstanding of Ansible hostvars. I am playing the template task from my playbook for 3 hosts, inventory file is below. Here is the playbook task:

```
- name: Template a HAProxy config
  template:
    src: ./haproxy.cfg.j2
    dest: /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'
```

This is my sample inventory file:

```
server10 ansible_host=192.168.70.15
server20 ansible_host=192.168.70.20
server30 ansible_host=192.168.70.25

[servergroup]
server10
server20
server30
```

And this is a part of my `*.j2` config file:

```
{% for host in hostvars %}
  server {{ host }} {{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to get something like that:

```
      server server10 192.168.70.15
      server server20 192.168.70.20
      server server30 192.168.70.25
```

Here is the problem - i'm getting something like that:

```
      server server10 192.168.70.15
      server server30 192.168.70.15
      server server10 192.168.70.15
```

How to use the IP variable correctly?

Answer (score 1):

`ansible_default_ipv4.address` is the default ip4 address of the host your are currently running the task on, i.e. `server10` if I beleive your example inventory.

If you want facts from an other host, you need to navigate those through the `hostvars` magic dictionary. See [the relevant section in the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-information-about-other-hosts-with-magic-variables) for more info.

In your case, you can fix your template like so:

```
{% for host in hostvars %}
  server {{ host }} {{ hostvars[host].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}
{% endfor %}
```

Please note that `ansible_default_ipv4` will only exist for a specific `host` if your previously gathered facts for that host.

Alternatively, you could use the info already registered in your inventory without having to gather facts in that case:

```
{% for host in groups['servergroup'] %}
  server {{ host }} {{ hostvars[host].ansible_host }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Got an error. gather_facts: yes

<code>"AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object' has no attribute 'ansible_default_ipv4'"</code>

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Which ansible version are your running? Try to replace with `hostvars[host].ansible_facts.default_ipv4.address`. If this still fails, triple check your playbook is actually gathering facts for all needed hosts when it starts.